# Nginx put/post save body in container

Tags: docker, nginx, post, https, put

I am trying to confure a post or put request with nginx for save the loaded file in another docker container. I have try to configure nginx take a request like https://myWeb/file/a/b/FileUpdate/fileName.txt and save fileName.txt in nginx container in route /etc/nginx/file, and, afther this, with a volume copy into another container.

however, with post request i get 301 and 403 forbidden i do not know how to solve it.
With put request i get 409 conflit and in traces i show that is said that "/etc/nginx/file" could not be created (21: Is a directory)

This is my nginx.conf

````http
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/cert/cert.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/cert/certkey.pem";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        
        location  ~ /FileUpdate/ {
            dav_methods PUT;
            alias /etc/nginx/fileData;
            client_body_temp_path /;
            create_full_put_path  on;
            dav_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
            #create_full_put_path on;
            #dav_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

   }
    
}```

And this my docker-compose.yml

``` nginx:
    container_name: ing_platform_nginx
    image: localhost:5000/nginx:1.23.2
    build:
      context: nginx_volume
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_volume/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx_volume/certs/certkey.pem:/etc/nginx/cert/certkey.pem
      - ./nginx_volume/certs/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/cert/cert.pem
      - ./nginx_volume/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx_volume/help:/usr/share/nginx/help
      - ./nginx_volume/filemng:/etc/nginx/filemng
    ports:
      - 8884:8884
      - 8887:8887
      - 8085:8085
      - 443:443
      - 80:80 # We could hide this port to force ssl connections
    networks:
      - dockerized-monitoring_common-net
    restart: always```

how can i solver put or post error?
````